# Acrobat XI Pro like pdf reader

Tags: application-development, pdf, adobe-reader

How do I install a PDF reader like "acrobat XI pro" which lets me highlight text, has text recognition and lets me combine and convert PDF from and to other formats?

Answer (score 2):

I run kubuntu and the KDE dedktop, and use Okular. It is a Qt4 app that has those capabilities.  I believe its more capable for markup than Evince. You can install it even if you use the default Ibuntu desktop.

Comment: I have okular but i couldn't find the option to highlight text anywhere

Answer (score -2):

Another option with the features you're looking for is PDF Studio by Qoppa. It's not free, but a lot more reasonable than what I recall paying for Acrobat years ago. The standard version is under $100 and the pro version is only a bit more. Check it out at www.qoppa.com/pdfstudio, I've been using the Pro version for a couple of years and really like it.

Comment: isn't the whole point of using open source is that we get free software?